# Perl static class properties

Tags: perl, oop, class, syntax, static

As I know, creating dynamic instances of a class (package) is like a hack on Perl syntax (using 'bless'). Perl doesn't support a keyword called 'class'; thus everything is limited.

The first limitation of Perl which causes difficulty in OOP is when creating **static class properties** and **static class methods**. Any solution?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For class-level variables there are two commonly used approaches:

```
package Bar;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub new { bless {}, shift };

# (1) Use a lexical variable scoped at the file level,
# and provide access via a method.
my $foo = 123;
sub get_foo { $foo }

# (2) Use a package variable. Users will be able to get access via
# the fully qualified name ($Bar::fubb) or by importing the name (if
# your class exports it).
our $fubb = 456;
```

Example usage:

```
use Bar;

my $b = Bar->new;
print "$_\n" for $b->get_foo(), $Bar::fubb;
```

Comment: i don't know why $Bar::fubb always gives me blank, and thus i have to use 'get','set' methods to read & write the variable in package

Comment: @nicola with `our` it is possible to access the variable externally, with `my` it is not. If it's still not working with `our` I'd be interested to see the code.

Answer (score 6):

In this day and age, if you really want to do OOP with Perl, you'd be well advised to use an object framework like [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual.pod) that will help clean up the crufty syntax.  It will make doing OO in Perl hurt a lot less, and if you use extensions like MooseX::Declare, it'll be even sweeter.

I don't do a whole lot of OO stuff, but I think I know what you're trying to do, and I do believe Moose can make it straight forward to do so.

Comment: Static things with Moose have been [explained here with a comprehensive code example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587157/how-can-i-set-a-static-variable-that-can-be-accessed-by-all-subclasses-of-the-sa).

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution:

```
package test;

my $static_var = undef;

#constructor not needed

#static method to set variable
sub set_var {
    my ($value) = @_;
    $static_var = $value;
}

#static method to get variable value
sub get_var {
    return $static_var;
}

1;
```

According to http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/UnixReview/col46.html, it doesn't seem possible to access those variables in package directly. Maybe there must be `get`, `set` methods to access them.

As said in the above article:

> There's also no syntax that would let any other code outside of this code access those variables, so we can be assured that our variables won't be changing mysteriously.

I don't really know whether that author is right.

Comment: however i still don't know how to access the $static_var directly yet, presently i can access it only through subroutines like set_var, get_var above

Comment: "i don't really know whether that author is right". You can generally trust merlyn on these things :-)

Comment: what davorg was trying to say via a healthy dose of irony is that merlyn is actually Randal Schwartz (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randal_L._Schwartz), (co)-author of several main Perl books (Camel/Llama/Alpaka O'Reilly Perl books among them) and one of the oldest, most well known and respected Perl hackers.

Comment: but it seems accessible if we declare the variable with 'our' keyword?

Comment: 'our' is sort of a fudge, it allows you code to pass the 'use strict' test, but basically means there is no access control on the variable.

Answer (score 0):

A standard package variable behaves as a class variable

```
package foo;

my $bar;

1;
```

then:

```
$foo::bar=1;  # or whatever
$foo::bar++;
print $foo::bar, "\n";
```

Comment: the "print $foo::bar" gives me a blank string, u know y?

Comment: That's never going to work. my $bar creates a lexical variable, but $foo::bar is trying to access a package variable.

Comment: You need to `s/my/our/`, `our` creates a short lexical alias for a package variable, whereas `my` creates a lexical variable that does not live in a package (and is thus not accessible via a fully qualified package name)