# How do I use Perl XML::LibXML to parse XML data using findnodes and findvalue

Tags: xml, perl

I am trying to parse XML using XML::LibXML module. The XML data structure has node called `<row>` which encloses two child nodes `<key>` and `<value>`. I want to parse each of these `<row>` and build a hash data structure. I could come up with below code to achieve it but I feel there would be a better way to do it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use XML::LibXML;

my $XML=<<EOF;
<config>
    <row>
        <key>
            <A1>alpha</A1>
            <A2>beta</A2>
            <A3>cat</A3>
            <A4>delta</A4>
        </key>
        <value>
            <B1>eclipse</B1>
            <B2>pico</B2>
            <B3>penta</B3>
            <B4>zeta</B4>
        </value>
    </row>
    <row>
        <key>
            <A1>tom</A1>
            <A2>harry</A2>
            <A3>bob</A3>
            <A4>ben</A4>
        </key>
        <value>
            <B1>TAP</B1>
            <B2>MAN</B2>
            <B3>WORK</B3>
            <B4>MAINTAIN</B4>
        </value>
    </row>
</config>
EOF

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc  = $parser->parse_string($XML);

my %hash;
my $i = 1;

foreach my $node ($doc->findnodes('/config/row/key')) {
    foreach my $tag ('A1', 'A2','A3','A4') {
        $hash{'KEY' . $i}{$tag} = $node->findvalue( $tag );
    }
    $i++;
}

$i = 1;

foreach my $node ($doc->findnodes('/config/row/value')) {
    foreach my $tag ('B1', 'B2','B3','B4') {
        $hash{'KEY' . $i}{$tag} = $node->findvalue( $tag );
    }
    $i++;
}

print Dumper \%hash;
```

**Output**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'KEY2' => {
                      'A3' => 'bob',
                      'B3' => 'WORK',
                      'B1' => 'TAP',
                      'A1' => 'tom',
                      'B4' => 'MAINTAIN',
                      'B2' => 'MAN',
                      'A2' => 'harry',
                      'A4' => 'ben'
                    },
          'KEY1' => {
                      'A3' => 'cat',
                      'B3' => 'penta',
                      'B1' => 'eclipse',
                      'A1' => 'alpha',
                      'B4' => 'zeta',
                      'B2' => 'pico',
                      'A2' => 'beta',
                      'A4' => 'delta'
                    }
        };
```

Actually, instead of creating imaginary keys ( KEY1 , KEY2 .. ) , I would like to have `<A1>` node's value to be considered as key for each  section. Can someone please help me out here.

**Desired output:**

```
'tom'   => {
             'A3' => 'bob',
             'B3' => 'WORK',
             'B1' => 'TAP',

             'B4' => 'MAINTAIN',
             'B2' => 'MAN',
             'A2' => 'harry',
             'A4' => 'ben'
           },
'alpha' => {
             'A3' => 'cat',
             'B3' => 'penta',
             'B1' => 'eclipse',

             'B4' => 'zeta',
             'B2' => 'pico',
             'A2' => 'beta',
             'A4' => 'delta'
           }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***"I would like to have `<A1>` node's value to be considered as key for each section"***

This solution creates a hash for each *row* element and pushes it onto the `@rows` array. Unlike the original it reads the XML data from a file called `config.xml`

The tags for the `A*` and `B*` elements are ignored -- it is simply assumed that the keys and values are in the same order

The main loop iterates over the `row` elements, and for each row, a list of the `key` and `value` child elements is converted to their text values with a `map`. Then a  hash is built and pushed onto the array

I've used `Data::Dump` to display the resulting data structure as I believe it is far superior to `Data::Dumper`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => 'config.xml' );

my @rows;

for my $row ($doc->findnodes('/config/row')) {

    my @keys   = map $_->textContent, $row->findnodes('key/*');
    my @values = map $_->textContent, $row->findnodes('value/*');

    my %row;
    @row{@keys} = @values;
    push @rows, \%row;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \@rows;
```

#### output

```
[
  { alpha => "eclipse", beta => "pico", cat => "penta", delta => "zeta" },
  { ben => "MAINTAIN", bob => "WORK", harry => "MAN", tom => "TAP" },
]
```

---

#### Update

Here's a variation that complies with your *desired output*. Thanks to [choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba) for pointing it out to me

It's a very similar approach to my original one above, but it builds a hash instead of an array and uses the elements' tag names as keys instead of the key/value relationship that I guessed you would want

I should say that I'm very doubtful about your choice of data structure; for instance, I see no need to exclude the `A1` key from the subsidiary hash just because its value is used to identify the row. I would also be surprised if it wouldn't be better to use the `key` and `value` strings as keys and values. But it may also be that the XML tag names are badly chosen and your choice is optimal, and I have no way of knowing

Here's the Perl code. which reads from the `config.xml` file as before. If you would prefer to keep the `A1` hash element as I described then you can just change the `elsif` to an `if` and it will happen

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => 'config.xml' );

my ( %data, $section);

for my $row ( $doc->findnodes('/config/row') ) {

    for my $item ( $row->findnodes('key/* | value/*') ) {

        my ($key, $val) = ( $item->tagName, $item->textContent );

        if ( defined $section ) {
            $data{$section}{$key} = $val
        }
        else {
            $section = $val;
        }
    }
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \%data;
```

#### output

```
{
  alpha => {
    A2 => "beta",
    A3 => "cat",
    A4 => "delta",
    B1 => "eclipse",
    B2 => "pico",
    B3 => "penta",
    B4 => "zeta",
  },
  tom => {
    A2 => "harry",
    A3 => "bob",
    A4 => "ben",
    B1 => "TAP",
    B2 => "MAN",
    B3 => "WORK",
    B4 => "MAINTAIN",
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first XPath expression selects the A1s, the second one selects all the A* and B* in the same row (except the A1 itself).

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::LibXML;

my $xmlstring = << '__XML__';
<config>
    ...
</config>
__XML__

my $xml = 'XML::LibXML'->load_xml(string => $xmlstring);
my $root = $xml->documentElement;

my %hash;
for my $a1 ($root->findnodes('/config/row/key/A1')) {
    for my $node ($a1->findnodes('(../../key/*[not(self::A1)] | ../../value/*)')) {
        $hash{ $a1->textContent }{ $node->getName } = $node->textContent;
    }
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \%hash;
```

#### output

```
{
  alpha => {
    A2 => "beta",
    A3 => "cat",
    A4 => "delta",
    B1 => "eclipse",
    B2 => "pico",
    B3 => "penta",
    B4 => "zeta",
  },
  tom => {
    A2 => "harry",
    A3 => "bob",
    A4 => "ben",
    B1 => "TAP",
    B2 => "MAN",
    B3 => "WORK",
    B4 => "MAINTAIN",
  },
}
```

Comment: Why the quotes in `'XML::LibXML'->load_xml` ? I'm sure you know that they're optional n a class method call. I also think you need some narrative

Comment: @Borodin: regarding the quotes, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16656174/1030675. They are nices than `XML::LibXML::`, but a bit less powerful.

Comment: @Borodin: The code was tested, please don't change it in a way that changes its output.

Comment: @Borodin: Here's where I learned to quote class names: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=980498

Comment: I apologise for my edit, but after all your original solution has no output. I've added just a dump and the corresponding output. I hope you can see what I meant by my original changes?

Comment: @Borodin: I don't. What I see is `is_deeply` same as the expected output in the question.

Comment: The OP has only his *actual* output, and it includes `A1` as a key. Your code explicitly excludes it

Comment: @Borodin: So what's that "**Desired output:**"?

Comment: Ah I see my misunderstanding. I overlooked `**Desired output**` because of the bad markdown. Your solution satisfies that admirably

Comment: *"Here's where I learned to quote class names"* I think I prefer to keep to the rule that lexical identifiers should never contain upper-case letters. That fixes a few other things as well and makes the code more readable